# emgu cv save image to file in vb

Tags: vb.net, image, save, emgucv

I have copied a webcam image capture tutorial from the web. It works OK. I want to watch a changing scene and save a captured image to disk when I push a button on the form. The button push is detected, but I am unable to save an image. Here is the main code. I have tried two save methods but neither works. What am I missing?

```
Sub ProcessFrameAndUpdateGUI(sender As Object, arg As EventArgs)
    imgOriginal = capWebcam.QueryFrame()            'get the next frame from the webcam
    If (imgOriginal Is Nothing) Then                'if we didn't get a frame
        Return
    End If

    If btnStackPressed = True Then                      'is button pressed?
        btnStackPressed = False                         'clear the button
        imgOriginal = capWebcam.QueryFrame()            'get the next frame from the webcam
    End If

    ibOriginal.Image = imgOriginal                      'display the current image in the imagebox
    cvSaveImage("C:\imagesaved.bmp", imgOriginal)       'save current image as bmp
    imgOriginal.Save("C:/MyPic.jpg")                    'save current image as jpg

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an answer. I don't understand the underlying facts. I saw a post on another blog that said the failure to save might be due to a Windows security issue and recommended saving to another disk. This closes the issue for me.

```
        imgOriginal.Save("C:\imgsaved.jpg")  'This doesn't work.

        imgOriginal.Save("C:\Photo_temp\imgsaved.jpg") 'This works.

        imgOriginal.Save("G:\Photo_temp\imgsaved.jpg")  'This works.

        imgOriginal.Save("G:\imgsaved.jpg")  'This works.
```